# Overriding .fetch() works with fake data, errors with urlRoot and actual Model ajax request

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I'm confused - I thought I had model binding working correctly, but it was only as a jsFiddle with faked ajax request. I've bound a model to a view, and if I override `.fetch()` and fake the response, everything works (I can update the model and the view updates on the page). However, when I *don't* override `.fetch()` and use the `urlRoot` param and wait for the response, I get errors.

Here is the working jsFiddle where a model is rendered after calling `.fetch()` with a faked response, than changed:

http://jsfiddle.net/franklovecchio/FkNwG/182/

So if I have an API call on the server side:

`/thing/:id`

With an example response for `/thing/1`:

```
{"id":"1","latitude":"lat1","longitude":"lon1"}
```

And I comment out `.fetch()`, I get the console errors:

```
load js core functions core.js:2
init model timeout app.js:114
initializer callback for history, routes app.js:95
App.Layouts.MyLayout onShow app.js:41
App.Regions.MyRegion onShow app.js:25
App.Models.Thing init app.js:55
App.ItemViews.Thing init app.js:87
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toJSON' backbone.marionette-0.8.1.min.js:9
Parsing App.Models.Thing.fetch() response: {"id":"1","latitude":"lat1","longitude":"lon1"} app.js:62
Thing: {"id":"1","latitude":"lat1","longitude":"lon1"} app.js:66
a Thing has changed, update ItemView! app.js:57

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'render' of undefined app.js:58

update model app.js:108

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'
```

The code with `.fetch()` commented out:

```
window.App = { }
window.App.Regions = { } 
window.App.Layouts = { }
window.App.Models = { } 
window.App.ItemViews = { } 
window.App.Rendered = { } 
window.App.Data = { }

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# App.Regions.MyRegion
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

class MyRegion extends Backbone.Marionette.Region
  el: '#myregion'   
  onShow: (view) ->
    console.log 'App.Regions.MyRegion onShow'

App.Regions.MyRegion = MyRegion

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# App.Layouts.MyLayout
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

class MyLayout extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
  template: '#template-mylayout'  
  regions:
    contentRegion: '#content'
    anotherRegion: '#another'
  onShow: (view) ->
    console.log 'App.Layouts.MyLayout onShow'

App.Layouts.MyLayout = MyLayout

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# App.Models.Thing
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

class Thing extends Backbone.Model

  urlRoot: () ->
    '/thing'

  initialize: (item) ->
    console.log 'App.Models.Thing init'
    @bind 'change', ->
      console.log 'a Thing has changed, update ItemView!'
      @view.render()

  parse: (resp) ->
    console.log 'Parsing App.Models.Thing.fetch() response: ' + JSON.stringify resp
    @attributes.id = resp.id
    @attributes.latitude = resp.latitude
    @attributes.longitude = resp.longitude
    console.log 'Thing: ' + JSON.stringify @
    @

  # If I don't override, I get an error.
  ###fetch: () ->
    console.log 'override ajax for test - App.Models.Thing.fetch()'
    resp =
      id: 1
      latitude: 'lat1'
      longitude: 'lon1'
    console.log 'Faked Thing response: ' + JSON.stringify resp
    @parse resp###

App.Models.Thing = Thing

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# App.ItemViews.Thing
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

class Thing extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
  template: '#template-thing'
  initialize: (options) ->
    console.log 'App.ItemViews.Thing init'
    # Bind
    @options.model.view = @

App.ItemViews.Thing = Thing

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# App.MyApp ...the Marionette application
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

App.MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application()

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# App.MyApp before init
# ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

App.MyApp.addInitializer (data) ->
  console.log 'initializer callback for history, routes'

  App.Rendered.myRegion = new App.Regions.MyRegion
  App.Rendered.myLayout = new App.Layouts.MyLayout

  App.Rendered.myRegion.show App.Rendered.myLayout

  # GET thing
  App.Data.thing = new App.Models.Thing(id: 1)
    .fetch()

  App.Rendered.thingView = new App.ItemViews.Thing(model: App.Data.thing)
  App.Rendered.myLayout.contentRegion.show App.Rendered.thingView

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# Test
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

App.updateModel = ->
  console.log 'update model'

  # Update the Thing with id = 1
  App.Data.thing.set
    latitude: 'somenewlat'

App.updateModelTimeout = ->
  console.log 'init model timeout'
  setTimeout 'App.updateModel()', 2000

App.updateModelTimeout()

$ ->
  data = { }
  App.MyApp.start data

​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of strange and confused things going on here. Fear not, all is not yet lost and the confusion can be sorted out.

Backbone's [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) is supposed to return a `jqXHR`, not the model itself. Your `fetch` implementation incorrectly returns `@parse resp` and your [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) returns `@` (which is also incorrect and sometimes two wrongs do make a right). The result is that this:

```
App.Data.thing = new App.Models.Thing(id: 1).fetch()
```

gives you a useful `App.Data.thing` when you use your `fetch` but it won't be right with Backbone's `fetch`. So your `fetch` is broken and you're not using the `fetch` correctly; then you try to give the `jqXHR` to your view as the model and your view sets `@view` on the `jqXHR` rather than the model:

```
initialize: (options) ->
  #...
  @options.model.view = @
```

So you end up with a `view` property on the `jqXHR` but the model has no `@view` (because `App.Data.thing` is not the model) and you get a "Cannot call method 'render' of undefined" error in your model's change handler.

You should be doing this:

```
App.Data.thing = new App.Models.Thing(id: 1)
App.Data.thing.fetch()
```

Now on to your `parse`:

```
parse: (resp) ->
  console.log 'Parsing App.Models.Thing.fetch() response: ' + JSON.stringify resp
  @attributes.id = resp.id
  @attributes.latitude = resp.latitude
  @attributes.longitude = resp.longitude
  console.log 'Thing: ' + JSON.stringify @
  @
```

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse):

> **parse** is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in *fetch*, and *save*. The function is passed the raw `response` object, and should return the attributes hash to be *set* on the model.

So `parse` is just supposed to massage the server's response into something that can be [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) on the model. Your `parse` is setting the attributes and returning `@`. The result is that you'll end up doing the equivalent of `m.set(m)`. So get rid of your `parse` implementation, yours is incorrect and you don't even need one.

Your model/view connection is backwards: views reference models, models don't reference views. You have this in your model:

```
initialize: (item) ->
  console.log 'App.Models.Thing init'
  @bind 'change', ->
    console.log 'a Thing has changed, update ItemView!'
    @view.render()
```

and this in your view:

```
initialize: (options) ->
  console.log 'App.ItemViews.Thing init'
  # Bind
  @options.model.view = @
```

You should be passing the model to the view when you create it (which you are so this is okay):

```
App.Rendered.thingView = new App.ItemViews.Thing(model: App.Data.thing)
```

and then the view should bind to the model:

```
initialize: (options) ->
    @model.on('change', @render)
```

and you can drop the `initialize` implementation in your model.

Also, you can (and should) declare classes directly in a namespace, don't do this:

```
class Thing extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
  #...
App.ItemViews.Thing = Thing
```

do this:

```
class App.ItemViews.Thing extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
  #...
```

Furthermore, the string/eval form of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) is evil should almost never be used. Don't do this:

```
setTimeout 'App.updateModel()', 2000
```

do this:

```
setTimeout (-> App.updateModel()), 2000
```

There may be more but hopefully this will get you started and solve your immediate problems.

Comment: Helpful, worded well, and funny. Thanks!